# how to add 2 buttons horizontally with 50% width for each in android?

Tags: android

how to add 2 buttons horizontally with 50% width for each ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Put them in a `LinearLayout`
2. Give them each `android:layout_width="0px"`
3. Give them each `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: but the width i need to be 50% of the with screen width, NOT to fill to it's content

Comment: @Adham set LinearLayout property "weightSum" to "2". Or set "weightSum" to "1" and "layout_weight" to ".5".

Answer (score 1):

Add both the buttons in linearlayout and give orientation as horizontal.And give width as zero dp for both buttons and layout_weight=1 for each.It will work.